# Can I add future/incomplete projects and accomplishments onto my resume?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I'm an 4th year undergraduate student who transferred to my current institution from community college during the pandemic. I'm applying to PhD programs this fall. Obviously, I missed out on a lot of opportunities I was hoping to take advantage of last year; this is not a unique experience. Yet, as a transfer student my first year on campus will also be my last.

I'm doing a lot this year, but none of the projects/accomplishments will be "complete" until after the application deadlines. For example, I've written a project proposal + lit review and have been trying to get a faculty member to help advise, but most of them are saying they're at full capacity with undergrads. Also, in my current lab, my PI said I've contributed enough this past year to become a co-author this coming spring when he publishes which is cool, but, again, that'll be in spring.

Can I mention these things on my resume specifically? If so, how? I have a lot of other things to discuss in my SOP so if I can put it in my resume, I would to. (Also, in case I'm not admitted this year, I'm applying to jobs and would like to start applying with the same "incomplete" content on my resume).

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common in a CV to have a section called "Work in Progress". It is fairly common in other application materials to have a discussion of "Future Work" or "Future Directions", though that is a bit less common in a CV. The SoP is an appropriate place for such things.

It is actually an advantage to list these sorts of things as it indicates activity in the field.

So, the current work is "in Progress" for the CV.